# How to disable Skype from using system tray (notification area) on Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, skype

I use AWN dock on Linux (which behaves much like Windows 7 panes, using one icon for launching an application and managing its windows). It loses Skype (as well as any other application) when it goes minimized to system tray (notification area). Can I disable Skype from minimizing to system tray favouring Win7-like behaviour?

Skype version I use is 2.1 beta, but I would not mind reinstalling it in favour of another version.

I use Arch Linux with all the latest kernel, x.org and xfce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Skype Linux main developer, there is no such option, XML-hackable or other (fresh info as of 2.2.0.62 beta). Your best bet is to look for a window manager or a component for it that let's you hide your tray icons in a generic way.

Comment: There is still no such option as of 4.1.0.20